# Android seekbar with float values

Tags: android, seekbar

How can I set the max value to `99,999` and min to `0.001` in seekbar ?

Comment: before asking question. you can search in Google right

Comment: This links may help you..[link1](http://webtutsdepot.com/2011/12/03/android-sdk-tutorial-seekbar-example/) and [link2](http://android.programmerguru.com/android-seekbar-example/)

Comment: @Ram kiran nothig helpful in that links, floats values dosen't mention

Comment: i suggested the basic examples there. with those you can find logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. The SeekBar widget only accepts ints for its max and current progress. You can't control the minimum, as it is always `0`.

You could multiply your required maximum and current progress values by a power of 10, such that the decimal goes away. The SeekBar will still show the same amount of progress as it would with a decimal value, as the progress is a ratio of `currentValue/maxValue`. As you'll be multiplying both by the same number, the ratios are equal. For example:

```
0.1/10 = 0.01
```

However, if you multiple both 0.1 and 10 by 10 to get rid of the decimal, you get:

```
1/100 = 0.01 //Same result
```

Answer (score 0):

SeekBar is taking only int value, not floating value if you want to set max value 99,999 and min value 0.001 then you can set max value 99,999*100 and min 0.001*100 then your ratio will display exactly.

And when you will display the percentage to user then get the value and divide by 100.

Answer (score 0):

Seekbar progress is an int type so u have to change the progress value by float value by dividing `Progress/1000.0` is as follows.

**here is the java code:**

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) 

{
    edit1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit1);
    float value= (float) (progress / 1000.0);
    edit1.setText((value)+"\n");
}
```

And layout u first try it as `android:max="99"`
The progress value will increment by **0.001** as you required upto the max value you can see those values in the edittext.