# Seekbar decimal increment value

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I want to create seek bar, I want increment like this seek bar

minvalue = 5, maxvalue = 10

seek bar value increments : 0 1 2 3 4 5 6

I want seek bar values like this : 5.10, 5.20, 5.30... 9.90, 10

How to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    float value = ((float)progress / 20.0);

    String yourprogress = String.valueOf(value+5.0f);
    // yourprogress is your desiger output

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
});
```

Comment: what problem you have faced??

Comment: It's giving me result 5.1, 5.05, 5.1, 5.15. And it's giving me value till 5.5 only. I have set android:max="10"

Comment: just change float value = ((float)progress / 20.0); to float value = ((float)progress / 10.0);

Comment: Ya! I tried that, as I wrote for below solution. But it's responding 5.01, 5.02, 5.03..

Comment: Yes, I achieved this. I set android:max="50" and float value = ((float)progress / 10.0); Thanks Digvesh!!

Answer (score 1):

```
aSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    float value = ((float)progress / 20.0);

  String progress = String.valueOf(value+5.0f);
    // value now holds the decimal value between 0.0 and 10.0 of the progress
    // Example:
    // If the progress changed to 45, value would now hold 4.5
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {}
```

});

Answer (score 0):

this is impossible with float. 
You have to make a workaround by multiply your increment.

see this response :
[duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15131877/1802663)