# How to increase seekbar value in floating

Tags: android, spinner

I want to increase the value of Seekbar by 0.25, here is myLayout.xml:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tvYMax"
    android:max="12"
    android:paddingBottom="12dp" />
```

I want the output like: 0,0.25,0.50,0.75,1,1.25,1.50,1.75,2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This it may be help to you

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(seekBar.getContext(), "Value: "+(float) progress/4, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

Comment: can i also set the progress at first time when app is open ? because of to set Progress value it will require integer value.

Comment: Then how can i set progress value in floating point when app is first time load, any idea about that ?

Comment: try this custom seekbar https://gist.github.com/niusounds/9505361 or https://jeffmenter.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/a-better-seekbar-for-android/

Answer (score 0):

You can not increase progress by floating value.

> The SeekBar widget only accepts ints for its max and current progress.
>   You can't control the minimum, as it is always 0.

for more detail : [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15131877/4628611)

Answer (score 0):

Let's say for suppose your seekbar starts from 0 to 12

```
android:max="48"
android:min="0"
interval = "1"
```

while displaying

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
{
  long progressToDisplay = progress/4.0f; 
  //0 -> 0.00,1 -> 0.25,2 -> 0.50 ..so on ... ,48 -> 12
}
```